# OXID turn "More" in categories off to show more categories

Tags: javascript, oxid

I use the Flow template and I need to turn off the "More" in the navigation when there are more categories than space in the navbar. I looked in the main.js and found a function, but when I comment this function out nothing happens. I tried another thing, and I think the Frontend does not react to my changes.

- Question 1: What is the best way to turn off the "More" to show more categories ( its for a customer... ) , and
- Question 2: If I change the main.js,do I need to change something in other files to show the changes in the Frontend? I deleted cache, but nothing changed!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is a configurable limit of categories in flow theme settings.
This should be the best way.

**About the JS part**: Haven't really working with the flow infrastructure, but i could imagine you are editing a file that gets compiled later. Flow theme uses `grunt` to do this. [More info here](https://github.com/OXID-eSales/flow_theme/blob/master/README.md).